# Máximo común divisor con 3 números

Tags: python

Me dieron la consigna de resolver el máximo común divisor de 3 números.
Así lo resolví entre dos:

```
num1 = int(input('Ingrese un numero: '))
num2 = int(input('Ingrese un numero: '))
def mcd(num1,num2):
    resto = 0
    while num2 > 0:
        resto = num2
        num2 = num1 % num2
        num1 = resto
    return num1
print('El maximo comun divisor entre ' + str(num1) + ' y ' + str(num2) + ' es: ' + str(mcd(num1,num2)))
```

Alguien me puede aclarar qué es lo que tengo que modificar para poder realizarlo con 3 números. Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

## Algoritmo de Euclides

Puedes seguir usando el algoritmo de Euclides que ya implementas, pero aplicando recursivamente la función, dado que:

```
mcd(a, b, c) = mcd(mcd(a, b), c)
```

Por ejemplo, reutilizando la función para el cálculo de dos valores mediante iteración:

```
def aux_mcd(num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
    num2, num1 = sorted((num1, num2))
    if num2 == 0:
        return num1
    while num2:
        mcd_, num2 = num2, num1 % num2
        num1 = mcd_
    return mcd_


def mcd(*numeros: int) -> int:
    if len(numeros) < 2:
       raise ValueError("Se deben proveer al menos dos enteros")
    mcd_ = 0
    for numero in numeros:
        mcd_ = aux_mcd(mcd_, numero)
    return mcd_
```

Ten en cuenta que 0 es el elemento identidad para el MCD, de forma que:

> mcd(0, n) = n
> mcd(n, 0) = n

o alternativamente usando `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce


def mcd(*numeros: int) -> int:
    if len(numeros) < 2:
        raise ValueError("Se deben proveer al menos dos enteros")
    return reduce(aux_mcd, numeros)
```

O usando recurción verdadera:

```
def mcd(*numeros: int) -> int:
    if len(numeros) < 2:
       raise ValueError("Se deben proveer al menos dos enteros distintos")
    num1, num2, *numeros = numeros
    num1, num2 = sorted((num1, num2))
    while num2:
        mcd_, num2 = num2, num1 % num2
        num1 = mcd_
    if numeros:
        return mcd(mcd_, *numeros)
    return mcd_
```

## Descomposición en factores primos

Otra opción es usar un algoritmo distinto para obtener el MCD, podemos calcular el MCD como el producto de los factores comunes elevado a la menor potencia:

```
from typing import Dict


def factorizar(num: int) -> Dict[int, int]:
    num = abs(num)
    factores = {}
    # Caso especial del 2 (primo par)
    while not num % 2:
        num /= 2
        factores[2] = factores.get(2, 0) + 1
    # Resto de posibles factores primos
    divisor = 3
    while num > 1:
        while divisor <= num:
            if not num % divisor:
                num /= divisor
                factores[divisor] = factores.get(divisor, 0) + 1
            else:
                divisor += 2    
    return factores


def mcd(*numeros: int) -> int:
    if (len(numeros:= set(numeros))) < 2:
       raise ValueError("Se deben proveer al menos dos enteros distintos")
    numeros.discard(0)
    min_numero = min(numeros)
    numeros.remove(min_numero)
    mcd_ = 1
    for factor, min_exp in factorizar(min_numero).items():
        for numero in numeros:
            exp = 0
            while not numero % factor and min_exp > exp:
                numero /= factor
                exp += 1
            min_exp = exp
        mcd_ *= factor ** min_exp
    return mcd_
```

Aunque solo se factoriza el menor de los enteros pasados, el algoritmo para la factorización es altamente ineficiente, dentro del problema, ya computacionalmente complejo de por si, de encontrar números primos. Se usa una simple división por tentativa con la única optimización de buscar impares como posibles factores. Es ineficiente pero simple.

Si se desea usar éste método para números relativamente grandes, usar un algoritmo más eficiente para encontrar los posibles factores primos es recomendable, por ejemplo, una simple tabla de Eratóstenes con los primos más pequeños ya precargados o al menos usar técnicas de memorización haría el algoritmo más viable para el cálculo del MCD de números grandes.

---

> ```
> >>> mcd(24, 36, 40)
> 4
> >>> mcd(16169, 24679, 20387)
> 37
> >>> mcd(375, 300, 165, 75)
> 15
> >>> mcd(3)
> Traceback (innermost last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "main.py", line 23, in mcd
>     raise ValueError("Se deben proveer al menos dos enteros")
> ValueError: Se deben proveer al menos dos enteros
> ```

Comment: O es `mcm` o es `MCD`. Hablas intercambiando los términos y no son lo mismo. Ojo con eso. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, si era un typo en la abreviación solamente, los algoritmos calculan todos del MCD (máximo común divisor) y no se usa el mcm (mínimo común múltiplo) en ningún lado. Corregido creo que no me he dejado ninguna... Gracias por el aviso, saludos.

Comment: Has puesto _reduce_ como `itertools.reduce`, aunque en el código está correctamente importado de `functools`.

Answer (score 1):

Pos... ¿pa'qué tanto brinco si el camino está parejo?

`math.gcd()` es lo que estás buscando

```
import math

num1 = int(input('Ingrese un numero: '))
num2 = int(input('Ingrese un numero: '))

print('El MCD de {} y {} es {}'.format(num1, num2, math.gcd(num1, num2))
```

Si lo quieres para más números, como te dijeron arriba mcd(a, b, c) = mcd(a, mcd(b, c)) = mcd(b, mcd(a, c)), etc. Entonces supongamos que tienes tus números en una lista:

```
nums = [12, 30, 60]

mcd = math.gcd(nums[0], nums[1])
for i in range(2, len(nums)):
    mcd = math.gcd(mcd, nums[i])

print(mcd)
```

Comment: La respuesta es válida, pero posiblemente sea un problema académico donde piden implementar un algoritmo, aunque hayan funciones predefinidas para hacerlo.

Comment: La verdad es que no lo menciona... solo le pidieron sacar el mcd con tres números, pero puedes tener razón 

Comment: Estoy haciendo un curso en el que recién estoy viendo funciones. El próximo tema es listas. La realidad es que el ejercicio lo saque de internet porque es a lo que mas se asemeja a lo que vi hasta ahora. Si saben de alguna forma de realizarlo solo con funciones, se los agradecería.